# Pgfplotstable converting zeros to -- in a knitr inline table

Tags: tables, formatting, pgfplotstable, knitr

how do I change each 0.0 to `--` without having to reference each as `string type` or making the whole table `string type`? The actual table is quite long and it would take too long to do it manually. For the same reason there would be a marked improvement in readability if the table wasn't cluttered up with lots of zeros.

The final table should look something like

```
Flow            Bibble         Bobble        Gumph
Extant             1              2             3
Intant             --             4             5
My sainted aunt    --             6             7
```

using for example the MWE below,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/Flow/.style={string type,column type={l}},ignore chars={\^^M},col sep=&,row sep=\\]{
    <<results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
        someStuff=read.table(textConnection("
                  Flow,   Bibble ,   Bobble ,   Gumph
                Extant,    1,           2,      3
                Intant,    0.0 ,        4,      5
       My sainted aunt,    0.0,         6,      7),header=F,sep=",")
    print(xtable(someStuff),include.rownames=F,include.colnames=F,hline.after=NULL,only.contents=T)
    @
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here is one pretty obvious solution, but I'm not sure its the right one. Would be open to deleting this query if its self-evident. Any comments appreciated... if I put the replacement `string replace` in `math-mode` it does the trick. so `...,string replace*={0.0}{$-$},` gives me the result I need.

Comment: The use of `string replace` sounds like the most simple solution. An alternative would be to write some TeX code which is simular to the `clear infinite` style (by copy-pasting from the source code). But that is clearly much more involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to knitr, but other general cases can be handled by first emptying the `@cell content` for unwanted entries and then post processing the empty cells with the desired result. Another example can be found in [Adjusting command behavior based on argument type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116246/adjusting-command-behavior-based-on-argument-type)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,%supress warnings
     table/zero to dash/.style={
        preproc cell content/.code={%
             \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@unprocessed cell content}\pgfmathresult%
             \pgfmathparse{(\pgfmathresult==0?int(1):int(0))}
             \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}\fi
        },
        empty cells with={--}% If empty place --
    }
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={Flow,Bibble,Bobble,Gumph},% declare column names
columns/Flow/.style={string type,column type={l}},
columns/Bibble/.style={
    zero to dash,
},
col sep=comma
]{
Flow,          Bibble,  Bobble, Gumph
Extant,            1 ,       2,      3
Intant,          0.0 ,       4,      5
My sainted aunt, 0.0 ,       6,      7
}
\end{document}
```

[image]